# How to fix the issue of 100% CPU usage when running webdriverio tests in parallel on selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid, webdriver-io

I have a webdriberIO javascript framework and I am trying to run about 200 tests in parallel on Selenium grid which is running on a different machine. I am running it on 8 parallel instances of chrome (8 nodes). When I start the execution, the CPU usage goes up 100% and some times, I get error connecting to the selenium grid. If I run only about 20 -30 tests, I don't see this performance issue.

Has anyone faced this issue? and is there any way we can fix it?

Thanks in advance